# Origin localhost: is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, xmlhttprequest, cors

Hello I am developing a project for my homework. First of all, I know there are many title about same problem, I looked at many of them, but I couldn't resolve this issue. If someone could help me, I will be very pleasured.

My ajax call is:

```
function submit(name,surname,source,destination,distance,volume,weight,price){

var xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+ "<shippingData><FIRSTNAME>" + name + "</FIRSTNAME>"+
                    "<LASTNAME>" + surname + "</LASTNAME>"+
                    "<SOURCECITY>" + source + "</SOURCECITY>"+
                    "<DESTINATIONCITY>" + destination + "</DESTINATIONCITY>"+
                    "<DISTANCE>" + distance + "</DISTANCE>"+
                    "<VOLUME>" + volume + "</VOLUME>"+
                    "<WEIGHT>" + weight + "</WEIGHT>"+
                    "<PRICE>" + price + "</PRICE>"+
                    "</shippingData>";





$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8084/ShippingDataService/webresources/generic/post',
        type: 'POST',
        data: xml_string,
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: 'application/xml',
        success: function (data) {

            alert("OK");

        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('POST failed.');
        }
    });
```

}

I have to use XML to transfer data, according to rule of my homework.
My server side is like that:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("post")
public ShippingData postXML(ShippingData content) {
    System.out.println("POST");

    return content;
}
```

Shippingdata class is:

```
package ship;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class ShippingData {

    public int SID;

    @XmlElement (name = "FIRSTNAME")public String firstName;

    @XmlElement (name = "LASTNAME")public String lastName;

    @XmlElement (name = "SOURCECITY")public String sourceCity;

    @XmlElement (name = "DESTINATIONCITY")public String destinationCity;

    @XmlElement (name = "DISTANCE")public int distance;

    @XmlElement (name = "VOLUME")public int volume;

    @XmlElement (name = "WEIGHT")public int weight;

    @XmlElement (name = "PRICE")public int price;

    public ShippingData() {

    }

    public ShippingData(int SID, String firstName, String lastName, String sourceCity, String destinationCity, int distance, int volume, int weight, int price) {
        this.SID = SID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.sourceCity = sourceCity;
        this.destinationCity = destinationCity;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
    }



}
```

I also tried to change ajax call url to 
`'localhost:8084/ShippingDataService/webresources/generic/post'` or
`'/ShippingDataService/webresources/generic/post'` but it doesn't work. I get the ajax error alert that I defined as "POST failed".
So how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Where did you define your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and what is the value?

Comment: @rekire I didn't define like this header, I couldn't understand where I have to define it.

Comment: What do you use on server side? WCF?

Comment: @rekire I don't have enough information about WCF. But I want to tell my development environment. I use netbeans, java web project. And Restful web service from patterns.

Comment: @rekire About the client side, I used html and javascript only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I solved the problem like that:

In the web.xml add this to between `<servlet></servlet>` :

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>"YOURPACKAGENAME".ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And add this class to your package

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest req, ContainerResponse contResp) {

        ResponseBuilder resp = Response.fromResponse(contResp.getResponse());
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");

        String reqHead = req.getHeaderValue("Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        if(null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals("")){
            resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
        }

        contResp.setResponse(resp.build());
            return contResp;
    }
}
```